# Symfony Impersonate User and onAuthenticationSuccess

Tags: security, symfony

On a symfony 2 project, i have a listener on :

**event**: security.interactive_login, **method**: onAuthenticationSuccess

I have just implements the impersonate user function of symfony (2.6.6).

But when i change user, i want to pass in this listener (or find another one like onChangeUserSuccess).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When impersonation is done, completely different event is fired: `security.switch_user`.

There is a great tutorial on how to catch that event here:
http://shout.setfive.com/2013/05/16/symfony2-and-impersonating-users-a-heads-up/

You could do pretty much anything then. Few months ago I implemented it this way to explicitly prohibit impersonation some top level admin users.